# Swing invokeLater() method not working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

In my main Swing frame I have this method:

```
public void receiveCommand(String command) {
    if (command.equals("enable")) {
        Runnable enable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                button1.setEnabled(true);                    
                button1.revalidate();
                button1.repaint();
            }                
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(enable);            
    }
```

basically, I'm trying to update the GUI (enable the button **button1**) from outside by calling the receiveCommand() method.

However this doesn't work, i.e **button1** is still disabled. What did I do wrong here?

**EDIT**:
Here is the declaration of **button1**:

```
private javax.swing.JButton button1;
button1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
button1.setEnabled(false);
button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            button1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Both **button1** and the **receiveCommand** method are in this **Game** class:

```
public class Game extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

The method is called from another class:

```
gameUI.receiveCommand("enable"); //gameUI is a Game object
```

**EDIT 2**: Thank you for all your help! It turns out to be a wrong reference after all, so all I did was trying to update the GUI of a wrong frame that hadn't been set visible yet. Silly me

Comment: "doesn't work" tells us little. Can you elaborate? Give us more information to go on?

Comment: Are you sure that the code block inside the `if` statement is being executed?  Maybe try `command.equalsIgnoreCase("enable")` instead?

Comment: I forgot to add: button1 is still disabled

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sure it goes inside the if

Comment: Chin, all I can say is that there is no way any of us can come close to guessing what is wrong based on the limited data you've presented so far. You need to tell us more, give us enough information so as to  understand the problem and not just scratching our heads in confusion.

Comment: I just want to ask the most suspicious piece of code first, since I believe there is something wrong with this method. Did I forgot to put something in or is this method OK as it should be? Like do I have to call some other update/redraw method?

Comment: All I can say with pretty good confidence: the problem is not in the code you're showing. The only thing wrong I see is unnecessary calls to revalidate and repaint. For all we know you could be calling `setEnabled(...)` on the wrong reference, but again,  you are not showing us anything that will allow us to help.

Comment: So speaking of references, where does the reference to button1 come from? Is this code being called from within the GUI class itself?

Comment: I added some more information

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

So anyway, this works.

```
public class TestInvokeLater {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestInvokeLater();
    }

    public TestInvokeLater() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 12));
            final JButton runMe = new JButton("Run me");
            runMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    runMe.setEnabled(false);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            }
                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    runMe.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(runMe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the *try invalidating and repainting it's container instead* advise ? There should be no need to call any of those methods.

Comment: @Robin I agree, but I've seen to many situations where "this shouldn't need to do done" solved by doing it

Comment: might be - but your example isn't one of those odd corner cases ... so it's clutter which might lead the unexperienced into a wrong direction